# Can't Locate/Delete an Installable Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I installed a form submit trigger for my project using ScriptApp around the beginning of May. The trigger has worked just fine however I now wish to uninstall the trigger and am running into problems. When I try to view all my current project triggers (*Resources > Current project triggers*), it returns that there are no associated triggers. Also when I try to run (*Resources > All your triggers*) it returns that there are no triggers shown.

I'd like to believe that this is the case, that the trigger in question has been somehow deleted but I don't believe that it is. To make sure the trigger didn't run, I de-authorized the script to run from my google [account settings](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions).

My suspicions that the trigger was not deleted were confirmed when I received a "Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Form Processing Script" which told me my script had failed 3 times because, "Authorization is required to perform that action."

These failure e-mails also contain a statement, "To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here." When I click on the link, there are no triggers shown...

Here's a look at the code i used to install the trigger:

```
function formSubmitTriggerInstall() {
  var formID = '1rOikLDUAqMWCB0ktjWzFE0oB6LmOHvXuzPAqyq0XLwE';

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('processForm')
    .forForm(formID)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
```

I have also tried to locate the trigger using ScriptApp but to no avail.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can eliminate this trigger or get the associated trigger ID?

One other note, since I installed the trigger, the google developer's website and documentation went through a major face lift and some of the page content appears to be updated as well. Not sure that would affect my triggers though.

Comment: If you think this truly is a bug and you haven't got some cross-account trigger and fail issue (can be caused by the script running under your id but the trigger hs been added by someone else) then add an error to the issues tracker. https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. Now that you say that it does sound more like a bug than a coding error. I'll check the issue tracker for any like issues and then report accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was confirmed that this was a big and it was fixed by the apps script team.